Do bias adjustments make sense in the context of measuring realized volatility to compare to implied volatillity?
I've been considering constructing a volatility cone to compare implied volatility to realized close-to-close volatility. However, I was wondering how the typical bias adjustments you might make to an estimate of standard deviation apply to stock returns.
For example, the intuition behind Bessel's correction is that the sample variance is reliant on the sample mean, which by definition minimizes the distance between observations in some way. So, if the actual population mean is in any way different from the sample mean, it's clear our sample variance would have underestimated the population variance.
It's standard practice with returns to assume the average is 0 for the sake of variance calculations. This seems justified because for the practical application of volatility trading, our delta hedged P/L (assuming hedging daily at close) is dependent on the actual magnitude of the returns, regardless if they are consistently 2% for every observation. So, if our volatility calculation isn't really reliant on the sample mean or population mean at all, wouldn't Bessel's correction just needlessly distort our actual realized variance?
I have a similar feeling about the adjustment you might make due to Jensen's inequality, since we would need to assume there's some "true" population variance we're trying to arrive at when it seems what's more important for our P/L is what was actually realized.

I wouldn't say it's standard practice to assume $\mathbb{E}(r_t) = 0$ and is very contextual. A good example of this is modelling S&P 500 returns over a long duration.
